# My questions disappeared in my index page (Django polls project)

Tags: python, django

I followed a tutorial on YouTube and my website showed the questions below as bullet point links on the index page:
"What's your name?" 
"what's your age?"

I think I may have deleted some part of the code by accident, as the header and footer still appear.

Should it be in the index page? attached below:

```
{% extends 'polls/base.html' %}

{% block main_content %}
      <h1 class="display-3">Choose a question</h1>

{% if latest_questions %}
    <ul>
        {% for question in latest_question %}
            <li><a href= '/polls/{{question.id}}'><b>{{question.question_text}}</b></a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>You don't have any questions. Please add some. </p>
{% endif %}[enter image description here][1]

{% endblock %}
```

Thank you!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmt4X.jpg

Answer (score 0):

check your `polls/views.py` does your index view have

```
context = {
    "latest_questions": latest_questions
}
```

return render(request, "html_file", context)

assuming  latest_questions is the variable storing the question query and did you also add context as the third argument of `return render`

Answer (score 0):

I was looking over the code a bunch of times, and couldn't see it. I was in fact missing an 's